# Count statement in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I have the following mysql statement but I'd like to use it with spring mongodb driver for java. How to convert it? Have looked at aggregation but have no clue how to.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedTime BETWEEN ('7:00:00' AND '7:14:59') THEN 1 ELSE 0) as firstCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedTime BETWEEN ('7:15:00' AND '7:29:59') THEN 1 ELSE 0) as secondCount,
FROM MyTable
Where username='Jim'
```

Mongo document:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5asd3ea3402984ca53"), username: "Jim", comment: "hi", CreatedTime: ISODate("2014-10-15T16:39:26.870Z") }
```

**UPDATE** on translating it to java using spring data:

When calling `getTemplate().executeCommand(match);` I get this:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "xxxxxxx" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such cmd: $match" , "bad cmd" : { 
"$match" : { "username" : "Jim"} , 
"$group" : {
    "firstCount" : { 
        "$sum" : { 
            "$cond" : { 
                "if" : { 
                    "$and" : [ [ { "$gte" : { "$CreatedTime" : { "$date" : "2014-09-20T16:02:10.924Z"}}} , 1 , 0] , 
                            [ { "$lte" : { "$CreatedTime" : { "$date": "2014-10-20T15:48:19.744Z"}}} , 1 , 0]]} , 
                "then" : { "$ifTrue" : 1} , 
                "else" : { "$else" : 0}
            }
        }
    }
}}}
```

Code that I use to get the JSON is [here](http://pastebin.com/6NDkJnBV) (its quite long).Query looks about the same that was suggested by @Wizard

What could be the trouble with $match? I read somewhere in Stackoverflow that old versions of mongodb do not support $match but I have Aug-2014 release so that can't be the case.

Comment: Just a mongo shell query would also clear things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
db.MyTable.aggregate([{
    $match : {
        username : 'Jim'
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : 0,
        firstCount : {
            $sum : {
                $cond : {
                    "if" : {
                        $and : [{
                            $gte : [ "$CreateTime", '7:00:00' ]
                        }, {
                            $lte : [ "$CreateTime", '7:14:59' ]
                        }]
                    },
                    "then" : 1,
                    "else" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        secondCount : {
            $sum : {
                $cond : {
                    "if" : {
                        $and : [{
                            $gte : [ "$CreateTime", '7:15:00' ]
                        }, {
                            $lte : [ "$CreateTime", '7:29:59' ]
                        }]
                    },
                    "then" : 1,
                    "else" : 0
                }
            }
        },
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think it is a better way than mine to do the job ;). nice answer (voted up)